# change an individual image in a gridview depending on a value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

i have 2 tables assignment and feedback, in a gridview it displays all the assignments, the assignments then get feedback. im then wanting to change the view feedback button in the gridview depending on if there is new feedback for example:

[image]

[image]

the feedback table has a state field in it so when its 1 i want that image button to change to the one with the +

Thanks in advance
Houlahan

Answer (score 0):

on ItemDataBound Event you can can change image's url

```
Image img = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("ImgId");
img.NavigateUrl = "~/images/othersource.png";
```

Comment: how would i determine if the row needed changing or not?

Comment: you can also get bound row. DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem; so while binding data from database you can determine if that image needs to change.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't like been cast to a datarowview : System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'VB$AnonymousType_0`4[System.String,System.Int32,System.DateTime,System.Int32]' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

Comment: you arent binding dataset right? try to cast object type you are using while binding.  you might post your bind code. another suggestion bind check flag ( whatere this image should be different or not) to an invisible label. and use label's value. Label l = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblInvisible); if ( lblInvisible.Text == "1") { //use another image.}

Comment: Dim dr As DataRowView = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView) e.row.DataItem gives me the row and the data that i want but it wont cast to datarowview